# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Update::update(), 0 passed nd exactly 7 expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

I want to update datas in database in Laravel, but I get error.
Here is my Route:

```
Route::post('/resetPOST', [App\Http\Controllers\Update::class, 'Update'])->name('id');
```

Here is my page:

```
<form method="POST" action="/resetPOST">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">  
<input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required value="{{ Auth::user()->surname }}">  
<input type="text" name="middlename" class="form-control" required value="{{ Auth::user()->middlename }}">  
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">  
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" class="form-control" required value="{{ Auth::user()->dateofbirth }}">  
<input type="text" name="idnumber" class="form-control" required value="{{ Auth::user()->idnumber }}">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" >Изменить</button>

</form>
```

Here is my App\Http\Controllers\Update code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Update extends Controller
{
    function update($id, $name, $surname, $middlename, $email, $datebirth, $idnumber){
        echo $id;
        // DB::table('users')-->where('id', '=', $id ->update(['name' => $name,'surname' => $surname,'middlename' => $middlename,'email' => $email,'datebirth' => $datebirth, 'idnumber' => $idnumber]));
    }
    
}
```

This is my error:

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Update::update(), 0 passed in D:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\laravel\right-univercity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 7 expected
```

Comment: Parameters are taken from the route, your route has _no_ parameters, your method expects 7 though. Use the Request to get the values submitted

Comment: Why would he want route parameters when he is dealing with a form. Remove all parameters from your controller function, and build the values with `request()->input('surname')` etc.

Comment: You definitely should not have `id` in your form. A user would be able to manipulate that and update anyones profile. `id` should just be taken from `Auth::user()->id` (within your update method) without ever appearing in your form.

Comment: you should relearn Laravel's Route and Controller. This is totally wrong. Just fixing this issue will not do any good to you if you don't have proper understanding of the framework and the language

Comment: @brombeer "Parameters are taken from the route, your route has no parameters". I mean bad guidance had me assuming that was what you were trying to portray.

Comment: @zanderwar Nope, that was an explanation of where (method) parameters are taken from. "_Use the Request to get the values submitted_" is the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should not have `id` in your form. A user would be able to manipulate that and update anyones profile. `id` should just be taken from `Auth::user()->id` (within your update method) without ever appearing in your form.

Try changing to this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Update extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
        // do the same for everything else.. 
        // echo $name;

        DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->update([
                'name' => $name
            ]);

        redirect()->back();
    }
}
```